# Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times and nun on background in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, location, background-task

I want my app keep running at all times. I have set the location on background mode in `info.plist`. And I also add the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` in `UIApplication` class. It keep my app running in background maximum 45-120 minutes.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you called `startUpdatingLocation`?  You don't need to begin a background task. If you have "always" location permission then your location delegate will get called anytime a new location is determined

Comment: Yes. I called the startUpdatingLocation and it call the delegate every time. but after 45-120 minutes app suspended. When we open the app it will open from the beginning.

Comment: Have you set `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to false?  What do you do in the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method?

Comment: No, I am not setting the pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically to false. In didUpdateLocations we stored the location in a array.

Comment: Try setting that property to false

Comment: Ok. I will add and let you know.

Comment: @SumitavaDatta were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: No, not solved...

Answer (score 1):

> For tasks that require more execution time to implement, you must
>   request specific permissions to run them in the background without
>   their being suspended. In iOS, only specific app types are allowed to
>   run in the background:
>
> Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
>   such as a music player app Apps that record audio content while in the
>   background Apps that keep users informed of their location at all
>   times, such as a navigation app Apps that support Voice over Internet
>   Protocol (VoIP) Apps that need to download and process new content
>   regularly Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
>   Apps that implement these services must declare the services they
>   support and use system frameworks to implement the relevant aspects of
>   those services. Declaring the services lets the system know which
>   services you use, but in some cases it is the system frameworks that
>   actually prevent your application from being suspended.

You can find some suggestions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already checked the Background Mode Location Updates in Capabilities section.